# How to set up Google Domains Dynamic DNS with Node.js & express?

Tags: node.js, express, dns

I have set up a Node.Js website on my Raspberry Pi running express.

I want to update my google DNS domain, using Dynamic DNS, from Node.JS/Express

What I have attempted:

```
function domainUpdate() {
    console.log(`[SERVER] Posting to Google's Servers...`)
    let username = process.env.USERNAME || ``;
    let password = process.env.PASSWORD || ``;
    let hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || ``;
    let url = `https://${username}:${password}@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=${hostname}`;

    https.request(url, (res) => {
        console.log(`status - ${res.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`output - ${res.complete}`)
    }).on("error", (e) => {
        if (e) throw e
    })
```

Using curl commands it would look something like this:

`curl https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=$HOSTNAME&myip=$IP_ADDRESS`

there is no output except from "[SERVER] Posting to Google's Servers..."

Comment: relevant reading:
https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083

http://www.farrellf.com/projects/software/2016-05-03_Setting_Up_a_Raspberry_Pi_Web_Server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) a try for making the actual request.  It handles a lot of the heavy lifting for you:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function domainUpdate() {
    console.log(`[SERVER] Posting to Google's Servers...`)
    let username = process.env.USERNAME || ``;
    let password = process.env.PASSWORD || ``;
    let hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || ``;
    let url = `https://${username}:${password}@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=${hostname}`;

    axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(`status - ${res.status}`);
      console.log(`output - ${res.data}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    })
}
```

It looks like that endpoint returns a 200 as long as the request is formatted properly.  The [Google support article](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083) that you linked to lists the possible responses, which will be in the `data` property of your Axios response object.